# Select records from table with inner join and where condition

Tags: mysql, join

This is the first time I use the JOIN method and I don't get very well.
I have got this tables(`$SupportUserTable` and `$SupportUserPerDepaTable`):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_user_departments` (
`id`                BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`department_id`     BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
`department_name`   VARCHAR(70)             NOT NULL,
`user_id`           BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')           NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`department_name`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

and this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_users` (
`id`                BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name`              VARCHAR(50)                 NOT NULL,   
`mail`              VARCHAR(50)                 NOT NULL,   
`password`          VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
`reg_key`           VARCHAR(260)                NOT NULL,
`tmp_password`      VARCHAR(31)                 NULL,
`ip_address`        VARCHAR(50)                 NOT NULL,
`status`            ENUM('0','1','2','3','4')   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '3',
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')               NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`mail_alert`        ENUM('no','yes')            NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'yes',
`assigned_tickets`  INT(5)  UNSIGNED            NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`solved_tickets`    BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`mail`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55;
```

and this is what I have writtenquery:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name  
FROM ".$SupportUserTable." a 
INNER JOIN ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." b 
ON (a.id=b.user_id)  
WHERE  a.status='2' OR b.department_id=? 
ORDER BY a.status ASC, a.name ASC
```

Basically I want to retrieve all the id and name from the first table where:

- the `status` in the first table is 2
- the `department_id` in the second table is equal to a value, in this case select first table id equal to second table user_id

Reformulated:
The query must match one of those conditions:

- a.status='2'=> retrieve the a.name and a.id
- a.department_id=value => retrieve the a.id and a.name where a.id=b.user_id

But I can't retrieve any record.

Comment: Where you say "=>" do you mean ">="?

Comment: it would be highly unlikely the table 1 id is equal to the user_id from table 2

Comment: @Strawberry: I mean the math logical operator, it means "in this case", it's not part of the query

Comment: @Bohemian: what do you mean?

Comment: The test `(a.id=b.user_id)` will never me true, except by chance

Comment: @Bohemian; why not? the user_id field of the first table is equal to the id of the second one, razorphyn_support_user_departments contains a list of users picked from razorphyn_support_users

Comment: Do you really have a match that has status='2' OR b.department_id=? Maybe you meant to say they have both and you should use `AND` instead of `OR`?

Comment: The query must match one of those contidions, if a.status='2'=> retrive the a.name and a.id or if a.department_id=value => retrive the a.id and a.name where a.id=b.user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimal query (for mysql only) will be

```
select distinct id,name from 
 (
  SELECT a.id,a.name  
   FROM ".$SupportUserTable." a 
   WHERE  a.status='2' 
  UNION (
   SELECT a.id,a.name  
     FROM  ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." b 
     left JOIN  ".$SupportUserTable." a
          ON a.id=b.user_id  
     WHERE b.department_id=? and  a.id is not null
   )
) as  tab 
ORDER BY tab.id ASC, tab.name ASC
```

So it will got first all raws with status 2.

After that union with all raws with deparment_id=?(and check that user exist).

After that sort.

Due to mysql planner's issues this is most likly be optimal(if you have indexes on status and deparment_id)

Comment: `Unknown column 'tab.status' in 'order clause'`